# Where is documentation for the CLI for the GameCredits Core for Windows?

Tags: wallet, cli

I am using GameCredits. I installed the node software locally and synced all the content. However, no helpfile seems to come with the software and I don't know how to start. I am quite new to this world of blockchains.

Could you point please to an official documentation regarding the CLI? I'm somehow struggling with the QT version, but perhaps learning to use the CLI could be useful to build a web interface of my own. I would like to, sooner or later, use it as integrated in a game of my own, but I don't know how to start.